# Got MethodID of RefenceType that is not a member of the ReferenceType

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jive

I am trying to debug an Java Web application, and for the first time I used [JIVE](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/jive/) , but I get all of the time 'Got MethodID of RefenceType that is not a member of the ReferenceType' in popup. Never seen that error in Eclipse (Luna) before. After a while another popup says: "Internal Error - An internal error...(blah, blah) Do you want to exit workbench."

Any idea what might be the cause for this error?

Comment: It migth a bug in Eclipse or JRebel. There is a report about this:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413848
but it has no solution yet provided.

Answer (score 2):

A bug was apparently fixed in Eclipse Photon that caused a race condition in lazy-initializing ReferenceTypeImpl.fMethodTable. This appears to have been particularly relevant to conditional breakpoints in multi-threaded code.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509259

This was fixed in internal build: I20170731-2000 and should presumably be available in major releases subsequent to that date.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182131/768795.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error today. Thought of sharing the answer as it might help others having same problem.

Cause of this issue is a probable memory leak in your code that jvm detects. In my case it was a thread that was hogging a lot of memory.

Hope this helps.